# Spring Integration jdbc stored procedure custom rowmapper

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jdbc

I am newbie to Spring Integration and am using Spring 4.2.4.
I am trying to invoke stored procedure with jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway. i am already using spring jdbc.

Stored procedure is returning cursor and am using customRowMapper like below

```
 new SqlOutParameter(A_RC, OracleTypes.CURSOR, null, new MyCustomDataExtractor())
```

MyCustomDataExtractor implements SqlReturnType and it returns custom object.

Now the question is how can I achieve this in SI jdbc stored proc.piece of my code here..

```
    ...
<int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="A_RC" type="#{T(oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes).CURSOR}" direction="OUT"/>
...
 <int-jdbc:returning-resultset name="A_RC" row-mapper="a.b.c.MyCustomDataExtractor"/>
...
```

Spring expect this as a row mapper. should I use any transformer here? Please advice.
Note : I have to return multiple resultset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually with the `CURSOR` type you are good to go with just a `returning-resultset` and `RowMapper` implementation.

With that you don't need to worry about any `SqlReturnType` and just map the row to your domain object directly.

I'm even sure you can rework your `MyCustomDataExtractor` to the `RowMapper` contract.

Note: with `returning-resultset` defintion you don't need to
specify the `sql-parameter-definition` for the same `OUT` param. The component identifies them correctly as a `OutParameter`.

And, yes you can have several `returning-resultset` for `CURSOR` parameters.

Comment: Thanks Bilan for your response, actually MyCustomDataExtractor having business grouping and it is returning Map instead of list of objects(RowMapper). Provided the solution which I have implemented..

Answer (score 0):

I added the return-type in the sql-parameter-definition and removed returning-resultset.

```
<int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="A_RC" type="#{T(oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes).CURSOR}" direction="OUT" return-type="ed"/>
```

and here "ed" is nothing but the bean reference for a.b.c.MyCustomDataExtractor.

```
<bean id="ed" class="a.b.c.MyCustomDataExtractor"/>
```

Comment: Sorry. Is it an answer to your problem? Then form it, please, in appropriate style to help other people with the same problem.

Comment: Added the snippet as per your comment..:)